# Разделить текст по строкам в Excel

Tags: excel

Есть таблица, в которой построчно занесены значений. Наименования столбцов такие (ID,Parent)
В строках столбца parent через разделитель занесены несколько значений.
Можно ли сделать так, чтобы таблица развернулась таким образом, чтобы вместо одной строки с id 81 например появилось столько строк, сколько значений в этой строке у столбца parent? То есть тут как бы нужна функция ТРАНСП() но с добавлением строк (их вставкой).
Вот файлик для наглядности
https://yadi.sk/i/CEl6cKlB74VyBA

Comment: Только программно, на VBA. Или формулами на другом листе.

Comment: @Akina Формулами на другом листе вполне подойдет. Подскажете?

Comment: @Akina подскажите, что у меня неправильно вышло - в комментарии к вашему ответу приложил файлик в котором попробовал воплотить в жизнь вашу мысль.

Answer (score 0):

На отдельном листе:

```
A1=2
A2=ЕСЛИ(F1="";A1+1;A1)
B1=ДВССЫЛ("shop_export_magazin_tuning_hall!R"&A1&"C1";ЛОЖЬ)
C1=ВПР(B1;shop_export_magazin_tuning_hall!A:B;2;ЛОЖЬ)
D1=НАЙТИ("|";C1&"|")
E1=СЖПРОБЕЛЫ(ЛЕВСИМВ(C1;D1-1))
F1=СЖПРОБЕЛЫ(ПСТР(C1;D1+1;255))
```

B1:F1 растянуть на B2:F2.
A2:F2 растянуть вниз насколько требуется.

Целевые столбцы - B и E.

Comment: А можно попросить вас в файле моем по ссылке сделать пример, а то я не силен в Excel, так бы я быстрее понял

Comment: Вроде мысль верная, но у меня почему-то не посчитались вторая и следующие строки https://yadi.sk/i/wCetjveIT9qkNw

Comment: Там небольшая ошибочка, в С2 поставьте формулу: `=ЕСЛИ(A2=A1;F1;ВПР(B2;shop_export_magazin_tuning_hall!A:B;2;ЛОЖЬ))` и копировать диапазон A2:F2 вниз